# 2 TextWatchers for 1 EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

I'm working on a simple android app project for myself. I found an article that made me decided to use TextWatcher. So simply, I add TextWatcher into my code. But here's the thing. I have designed 2 RadioButtons and 1 EditText. Both RadioButton will determine the format of my one and only EditText.

Here's how I want the apps to be reproduced:

1. If the user pressed Button A, then the input format for the Edittext will be like this:

   > ABCD  1234  EFGH  5678

   So, it has space in every 4 characters
2. If the user pressed Button B, then the input format for the EditText will be like this:

   > ABCD1234EFGH5678

   So, it has no space in every 4 characters

Even the user pressed the opposites again, the format of the EditText will follow the condition

**This is What I've tried:**

Use the if-else condition, and even create 2 TextWatchers, but still, the flow will be like this:

Make 2 TextWatchers to determine the case, but still here's what I've got:

1. The user pressed Button B, the Edittext format will be like `ABCD1234EFGH5678`
2. Then, The user pressed Button A, the Edittext format will be like `ABCD  1234  EFGH  5678`
3. When The user pressed Button B again, the Edittext format will be like `ABCD  1234  EFGH  5678` instead of `ABCD1234EFGH5678`

**How am I supposed to do to reach this approach?**

Here's my MainViewGenerator.java:

```
this.editTextNumberSpaceTextWatcher = new EditTextNumberSpaceTextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        super.onTextChanged(s, start, before, count);
        editTextString = s.toString();
    }
};

this.editTextNumberNormalTextWatcher = new EditTextNumberNormalTextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        super.onTextChanged(s, start, before, count);
        editTextString = s.toString().replaceAll(" ", "");
    }
};


withId(R.id.my_main_editText, new Anvil.Renderable() {
    @Override
    public void view() {
        if (!btnRadioGroupValue.isEmpty()){
            if (btnRadioGroupValue.equals(valueButtonA)){
                onTextChanged(EditTextNumberSpaceTextWatcher);
                text(editTextString);
            } else if (btnRadioGroupValue.equals(valueButtonB)){
                onTextChanged(EditTextNumberNormalTextWatcher);
                text(editTextString);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Here's my EditTextNumberSpaceTextWatcher.java:

```
public abstract class EditTextNumberSpaceTextWatcher extends PhoneTextWatcher {
    private static final String MY_NUMBER_FORMAT = "**** **** **** **** **** **** **** ****";

    public EditTextNumberSpaceTextWatcher() {
        super(MY_NUMBER_FORMAT );
    }

    @Override
    public char[] getSeparatorCharacters() {
        return new char[]{' '};
    }
}
```

Here's my EditTextNumberNormalTextWatcher.java:

```
public abstract class EditTextNumberNormalTextWatcherextends PhoneticTextWatcher {
    private static final String MY_NUMBER_FORMAT = "********************************";

    public EditTextNumberNormalTextWatcher() {
        super(MY_NUMBER_FORMAT );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use just one TextWatcher:

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
//here evaluate the value of radio button
 if(mRadioButton1.isChecked()){
      //set pattern
   }else if(mRadioBUtton2.isChecked()){
     //set another pattern
   }
}
```

Comment: I've done this before, but still, whenever Button A called, the EditText will only follow the Button A format even though I pressed the Button B @Igmer Rodriguez